# Owned attribute used in Vala function call creates "black magic C code"

Tags: pointers, vala

This is an example in Vala code.

There is a global Glib.Llist **vstack** that stores some pointers.

```
List<void*> vstack;
```

There is a **change_state** function that stored the second parameter in the global **vstack** list.

```
void change_state( enum..., void*, enum... );
```

This **goto_info** test function (which calls **change_state**) doesn't work because, when it returns, the pointer is deallocated even if it is stored in the list

```
// Vala source
void goto_info()
{
    StInfo sti = new StInfo();
    change_state( SUPS.INFO_PAGE, sti, StackDir.FORW );
}

// C output
void goto_info (void) {
    StInfo* sti = NULL;
    StInfo* _tmp0_ = NULL;
    _tmp0_ = st_info_new ();
    sti = _tmp0_;
    change_state (SUPS_INFO_PAGE, sti, STACK_DIR_FORW);
    _g_object_unref0 (sti);
}
```

But if I just add the **owned** attribute, the code works (the pointer is not deallocated at the end of the **goto_info** function), but I really can't understand what changes in the C output.

```
// Vala source
void goto_info()
{
    StInfo sti = new StInfo();
    change_state( SUPS.INFO_PAGE, ( owned )sti, StackDir.FORW );
}

// C output
void goto_info (void) {
    StInfo* sti = NULL;
    StInfo* _tmp0_ = NULL;
    StInfo* _tmp1_ = NULL;
    _tmp0_ = st_info_new ();
    sti = _tmp0_;
    _tmp1_ = sti;
    sti = NULL;
    change_state (SUPS_INFO_PAGE, _tmp1_, STACK_DIR_FORW);
    _g_object_unref0 (sti);
}
```

**IMPORTANT:** goto_info is the only function that changes if I add **owned**, nothing else is touched by the Vala compiler. Someone can explain where is the black magic hidden in this C output code? Why the second version works if the ref/unref call for the pointer are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note this line:

```
sti = NULL;
```

`sti` is set to `NULL` (while `_tmp1_` is passed to `change_state` instead), so the call to unref now is a noop:

```
_g_object_unref0 (sti);
```

Comment: Genius! The answer was so simple, but I really didn't expect a noop like this in an autogenerated code. Thank you very much for your fast support!